# Ogre3D texture being rendered in black color on OpenGL ES 2 (both iOS and Android)

Tags: android, ios, textures, opengl-es-2.0, ogre

I'm not knowing so much about CG/OpenGL, so I want to ask an issue about what I faced.

On Ogre 's RenderSystem_GL or RenderSystem_GLES2 or RendererSystem_GL3+ running on Windows are result nice output for texture like bellow

[image]

But on mobile device (iOS / Android), these terrain became black:

[image]

Note: I've research alot, someone 's answer said that it about the Mipmapping, should be disable Mippmapping?

Plus: I'm using Ogre 12 (migrated some code from Ogre 13.6.4), should I upgrade it to latest version?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've fixed, it bug in diffuse setting from `Ogre::ColorValue::White` to `Ogre::ColorValue{0.9999f, 0.9999f, 0.9999f, 1.0f}`

I don't know why, but i'm setting default diffuse to `Ogre::ColorValue::White`, on Windows it just fine, but on mobile it buggy like that